# Swift CoreData error unrecognized selector sent to instance when insert row

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am getting this error Thread 1: Exception: "-[Tasks initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000034da40" whenever I try to load my core data object.

- I have two entities (Tasks, Goal) with inverse many to many relationship.
- The goal entity has an attribute of transformable with a custom class [NSManagedObject] of task. I think this creates an issue when loading. but surprisingly when I save my context it doesn't crash

[image: Goal Entity]

[image: Task Entity]

Here us my subclass codegen of goal entity

```
extension Goal {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Goal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Goal>(entityName: "Goal")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: String?
    @NSManaged public var goalTasks: [NSManagedObject]?
    @NSManaged public var isComplete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var nsdate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var tasks: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for tasks
extension Goal {

    @objc(addTasksObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTasks(_ value: Tasks)

    @objc(removeTasksObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTasks(_ value: Tasks)

    @objc(addTasks:)
    @NSManaged public func addToTasks(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeTasks:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromTasks(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Here us my subclass codegen of tasks entity

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Tasks {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Tasks> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Tasks>(entityName: "Tasks")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: String?
    @NSManaged public var importValue: Int16
    @NSManaged public var isComplete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var list: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var nsdate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var goals: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for goals
extension Tasks {

    @objc(addGoalsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToGoals(_ value: Goal)

    @objc(removeGoalsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromGoals(_ value: Goal)

    @objc(addGoals:)
    @NSManaged public func addToGoals(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeGoals:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromGoals(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

here is how I am inserting a new goal object

```
@IBAction func setGoal(_ sender: Any) {

// Adding a task to the array
let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" // assigning the date format
 let goalVC = GoalViewController()

 let now = df.string(from: Date())
 let newGoal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Goal", into: context) as! Goal
 newGoal.setValue(goalTitle.text!, forKey: "name")
 newGoal.setValue(false, forKey: "isComplete")
 newGoal.setValue(goalDate, forKey: "nsdate")
 newGoal.setValue(now, forKey: "date")
 newGoal.setValue(goalSubTasks, forKey: "goalTasks")
    


do {
    try
    context.save()
    homeVC.loadGoals()
    print(newGoal)
    
    } catch {
    print("Problem while saving")
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and here the app crashes when this function is called where I load my load my goals into allGoals (array of [NSManagedObject])

```
    func loadGoals(){
    allGoals.removeAll()
    let requestGoal = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Goal")
    do {
        allGoals = try context.fetch(requestGoal) as! [NSManagedObject]
      print("loadTasks() fired!")
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I think the issue lies in the Transformable goalTasks attribute in Goal Entity but I am not sure what to do with it. any help is appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't store `NSManagedObjects` (or subclasses) as transformable attributes - you should use relationships.  But you have that as well (`tasks`).  Why do you need the `goalTasks` attribute?

Comment: i want to store an array of tasks object in my goal. because the goal entity has an array of subtasks in order to achieve the goal something like that

Comment: How is that different from the `tasks` relationship, which represents the `tasks` that are related to the `goal`?

Comment: I understand, then how do I assign certain tasks to certain goals?

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because you have specified the `goalTasks` attribute to be Transformable with custom class `[NSManagedObject]`.  When you fetch the `Goals`, CoreData uses the default value transformer to create an array of objects, which results in it calling the `initWithCoder` method of your `Tasks` class.  Since that method doesn't exist, you get the crash.

However, you do not need to use the `goalTasks` attribute: you have a `tasks` relationship defined.  To assign certain `Tasks` to certain `Goals`, you use the methods identified in the corresponding class definitions, eg. `addToTasks` and `addToGoals`, ie:

```
certainGoal.addToTasks(certainTask)
```

or

```
certainTask.addToGoals(certainGoal)
```

Note you need only use one of these methods.  Because the relationships are defined as inverses, CoreData will automatically update the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

@pbasdf answer is correct but has a limitation

cause of the goals are unique you cant add goals twice or more with a relationship.
in this case you have to add an intermediate entity which will hold the goals

in my case:

i have an app in which you have to go from start to 2 waypoints and back to start

the problem here ist to add the start-waypoint at last position

this does not work with pbasdf answer... cause you cant add them twice or more

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).